# Importing models in Django python

Tags: python, django, models

How can I import all models in the settings.py in INSTALLED_APPS? When i`m trying to insert some model there is an error occurred: "no models named app1_model"

```
-ProjectName
--ProjectName
---models
----__init__.py
----admin.py
----app_1_model
----....
----app_n_model
---templates
---__init__.py
---settings.py
---urls.py
---wsgi.py
--manage.py
```

^ Structure of project ^

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The INSTALLED_APPS is for apps not for models. Models are classes that live within your app, usually in `/«app_name»/models.py`.

I think you have misunderstood how a Django project is structured. Try working through a tutorial example.

a typical structure:

```
/«project»/«app_name»/models.py
```

and in settings:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [ ... '«app_name»' ... ]
```

Your path will contain the base project directory, so you can import your app where you need it.

And to use them:

```
from «app_name».models import *
```

Although it is always best not to `import *`, instead, name the classes you wish to import.

**To answer the question in the comment:**

If you don't like the idea of storing all your models in one file (even though it is normal to do this), you can create a module called models. To do this, create a directory called `/«project»/«app_name»/models`, inside it put `__init__.py` (to declare it as a module) and then create your files inside there. You then need to import your file contents into the module in `__init__.py`. You should read about Python modules to understand this.

**To answer the second comment question:**

To view models in admin, you should create an [admin file](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/) with model admin objects.

**And finally:**

Please read through the tutorials to ensure you have a thorough understanding of Django. Otherwise you're wasting your own time!

Comment: Can i have one folder called models and store all models within this folder?

Comment: Yes. That would be a module.

Comment: so how can i view all models in the admin panel?

Comment: "inside it put __init__.py (to declare it as a module) and then create your files inside there." i'm confused