# How to import a model to a file in Django

Tags: python, django

I have the following structure of the project:
[image]

I have folder modules. And I have file save_to.py
I need to import a model from bedienungsanleitung app. But when I try to do it, it gives an error

```
No module named 'manuals_project.bedienungsanleitung'
```

I try to do it the following way:

```
from manuals_project.bedienungsanleitung.models import Link
from .bedienungsanleitung.models import Link
from bedienungsanleitung.models import Link
from ..models import Link
```

What is the mistake? Can someone help me?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Importing models in Django python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15436235/importing-models-in-django-python)

Comment: No. It is said there: /«project»/«app_name»/models.py. I have the save import structure. from manuals_project.bedienungsanleitung.models ... But it doesn't work

Comment: In `views` you can use `from .models import Link`

Comment: Not. It's not view. It's a .py file

Comment: Your screenshot has multiple `bedienungsanleitung`s and multiple `manuals_project` s...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try:

```py
from bedienungsanleitung.models import Link
```

Comment: cannot import name 'Link' from 'bedienungsanleitung.models' (/home/atom/Desktop/Python/Manuals/manuals_project/bedienungsanleitung/models.py)

Comment: Hello. Yesterday everything worked fine. But today I have an error again.    from bedienungsanleitung.models import BaseLink
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bedienungsanleitung'

Comment: You need to check your directory structure, and you may be running this code from a different file. Could you provide the full stacktrace?

Answer (score -1):

```
from manuals_project.bedienungsanleitung.models import Link
```

I don't see that you have `models` under `bedienungsanleitung`.  Did you mean to say

```
from manuals_project.models import Link
```

Comment: Sorry. There was a mistake in structure. I've added a screenshot with the correct one